# linq list of list sum of number

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code like this(i have simplified the real case)

```
public class A
{
    public List<B> list { get; set; }

}

public class B
{
    public List<C> list{ get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }
}
```

I want sum the num values where date is today.
but there always an error because i have a list(in class B) in a list(in class A)
How can i do?
I try

```
        A a = new A();
        B b1 = new B();

        C C1 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today, num = 2 };
        C C2 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), num = 3 };
        b1.list.Add(C1);
        b1.list.Add(C2);
        a.list.Add(b1);

        B b2 = new B();
        C C3 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today, num = 4 };
        C C4 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), num = 5 };
        b2.list.Add(C3);
        b2.list.Add(C4);
        a.list.Add(b2);

        var tot = (from l in a.list
                   where l.list.Where(x => x.Date == DateTime.Today)
                   select l;
```

Comment: You want the sum of what? The sum of `A.list`? Are you saying because `B` is a member of `A.list` you want it to recursively sum? Your question is really unclear.

Comment: i want the sum of int property(num) in the class C, in the example is 6

Comment: I'd want to point out that using A,B and C as class names makes it harder for us (or well, is it just me?) to understand your code example. Using appropriate names would be cool next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` from the outer list to "flatten" the inner ones, like this:

```
var tot = a.list.SelectMany(bItem => bItem.list)
    // From this point on, you see a "flat" IEnumerable<C>
    .Where(cItem => cItem.Date == DateTime.Today)
    .Sum(cItem => cItem.num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your classes had unitialized storage:

```
public class A
    {
        public A()
        {
            this.list = new List<B>();
        }

        public List<B> list { get; set; }

    }

    public class B
    {

        public B()
        {
            this.list = new List<C>();
        }

        public List<C> list { get; set; }
    }

    public class C
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int num { get; set; }
    }
```

If you fix it you could use the SelectMany method.

```
        var tot = a
            .list
            .SelectMany(bItem => bItem.list)
            .Where(cItem => cItem.Date == DateTime.Today)
            .Sum();
```

With standard queue you could do it like

```
 var totLinq = (from bItem in a.list
               from cItem in bItem.list
               where cItem.Date == DateTime.Today
               select cItem.num).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check below code:

```
public class A
{
    public List<B> list { get; set; }

    public  A(){
        this.list  = new List<B>();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public List<C> list{ get; set; }

    public  B(){
        this.list  = new List<C>();
    }
}

public class C
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b1 = new B();

        C C1 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today, num = 2 };
        C C2 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), num = 3 };

        b1.list.Add(C1);
        b1.list.Add(C2);

        a.list.Add(b1);

        B b2 = new B();
        C C3 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today, num = 4 };
        C C4 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), num = 5 };

        b2.list.Add(C3);
        b2.list.Add(C4);

        a.list.Add(b2);

        var tot = (from bItem in a.list
                   from cItem in bItem.list
                   where cItem.Date == DateTime.Today
                   select cItem);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your scenario

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b1 = new B();

        C C1 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today, num = 2 };
        C C2 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), num = 3 };
        b1.list.Add(C1);
        b1.list.Add(C2);
        a.list.Add(b1);

        B b2 = new B();
        C C3 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today, num = 4 };
        C C4 = new C() { Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), num = 5 };
        b2.list.Add(C3);
        b2.list.Add(C4);
        a.list.Add(b2);

        //we took advantage of the SelectMany extension method.
        var cResuls = a.list.SelectMany(x => x.list).Where(x=> x.Date==DateTime.Today).Sum(x=> x.num);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of Today Value : {0} ", cResuls.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class A
    {
        public List<B> list { get; set; }
         public A()
        {
            list = new List<B>();
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public List<C> list { get; set; }
        public B()
        {
            list = new List<C>();
        }
    }

    public class C
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int num { get; set; }
    }
```